# Calling HTTPRequest takes too long for large number of calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asynchronous

I have to call 100,000 urls and I don't need to wait for the response. I have searched a lot . some people say there is no way to call http request without waiting for the response, also there are few answers for questions like mine that say to set  Method="POST".

The following is the source code based on all of them. I have tried to call the urls asynchronously using WhenAll.

The problem is this that when I see CPU usage in task manager, it is fully busy for 140 seconds and within that time the system is almost unusable.

```
protected async void btnStartCallWhenAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make a list of web addresses. 
    List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList(Convert.ToInt32(txtNoRecordsToAdd.Text));

    // One-step async call. 
    await ProcessAllURLSAsync(urlList);
}

private async Task ProcessAllURLSAsync(List<string> urlList)
{
    // Create a query. 
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> CallingTasksQuery =
        from url in urlList select ProcessURLAsync(url);

    // Use ToArray to execute the query and start the Calling tasks.
    Task<int>[] CallingTasks = CallingTasksQuery.ToArray();

    // Await the completion of all the running tasks. 
    int[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(CallingTasks);

    int total = lengths.Sum();
}

private async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url)
{
    await CallURLAsync(url);
    return 1;
}

private async Task CallURLAsync(string url)
{
    // Initialize an HttpWebRequest for the current URL. 
    var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webReq.Method="POST";

    // Send the request to the Internet resource and wait for the response. 
    Task<WebResponse> responseTask = webReq.GetResponseAsync() ;
}
private List<string> SetUpURLList(int No)
{
    List<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
    };

    for (int i = 1; i <= No; i++)
        urls.Add("http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx");

    return urls;
}
```

By the way the compiler hints that "this async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously consider using the await operator to await non-blocking api calls or await task.run(..) to do cpu bound work on background thread" for this line:

```
private async Task CallURLAsync(string url).
```

I don't know if this affect my problem or not but after searching same problem in other questions, they said  that I need to disable compiler message before this line.

Comment: Can you post the complete code for `CallURLAsync`? As it is, it won't even compile...

Comment: @Ron, Thanks for considering, I have also added the other source code for SetUpURLList method, but the source for  CallURLAsync is complete.

Comment: You should be `await`ing  `webReq.GetResponseAsync()`

Comment: @Jamie, Please let me know the source code